# Accidently typing :w in insert mode

Tags: vim

I am used to saving a lot. And usually after just typing few words I click ESC and type :w
But sometimes I forget to press ESC, or press :w Enter faster than ESC and it ends up messing my code with :w and newline.

What do you do then?

- Do you press u (to undo) and then type again,
- Or you (dd) the new
  line -> go up (k)  -> to end ($) and press (x) two times?

both of my previously suggested options are really frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it happens too often, why not map it to a no-op in insert mode:

```
 imap :w <nop>
```

There! Problem solved.

Comment: or inoremap :w<cr> <Esc>:w<cr>a so the save will happen anyway?

Comment: Avoid the character delay by using an abbreviation instead of a mapping. e.g. `:iabbrev :w <nop>`. You can spice this up with `<c-o>` to actually execute the save (See `:h i_ctrl-o`). You may also want to look into "Eating" the return character (See `:helpg Eatchar`).

Answer (score 1):

I would press C-W three times.

Comment: Delete 3 words backwards?

Comment: Yes (i_CTRL-W,) I suppose i-CTRL-U <BS><BS><BS> would more consistently work across auto indenting and whether or not the ':' is preceded by other punctuation. But treating everything as words is fast at a cost of potentially needing a little variation at the end.

Comment: I think C-W doesn't work for be because my vimrc isn't configured to backspace over new lines.

Comment: I get `backspace=indent,eol,start` with no vimrc even if I type vi instead of vim, but it is coming from debian distribution defaults. I think vim's default if it finds nothing is to emulate vi.

Comment: I just had an explicit `backspace=start`, I've updated with `eol`. Been meaning to do this for a while, thanks